# For Loop in MVC 4 From JavaScript value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I make a repeater type in the page.  In the page I have a quantity field:

```html
<td>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Quantity)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Quantity)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity, new { @id = "txtQty" })
</td>
```

When I want to add the item, which there could be several of the same item, just different serial numbers, I need to pop open a div with repeated fields for entering serial numbers:

```
for (int I = 0; I < *****; I++)
{
    <td>Serial Number:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextboxFor(x=>x.Quantity, new { @id = "txtQty" + 1})
}
```

In the JS:

```
function AddItem() {
    Qtys = parseINT($("#txtQty").val());
    $("#divSerials").show();
}
```

How can I do this?  Is there a better way?

Is this the way to do it?  I try this but 'i' in the HTML model statement is not recognized.

```
 if (parseInt($("#txtQuantity").val()) > 0) {
            $("#divSerialNumbers").show();
            var html = "<table>";
            for (i = 1; i <= serialquantity; i++) {
                html += "<tr><td>Serial Number:" + @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SerialNumber, new { id = "sns" + i }) + "</td></tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";
            $("#divSerialNumbers").html(html);
        }
```

Comment: It is not so clear what you are trying to do...
You want several text boxes? You can use array, and make TextBoxFor(x=>x.yourArray[i])

Comment: If I understand you correctly and you want to set the number of loops dynamically, there's no way to do that with Razor. You could use javascript and clone / duplicate the DOM section that contains the label and textbox, then set the new 'id' property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor code is parsed on the server **before** it is sent to the view. Javascript is client side code and is not executed until the browser receives the view. This line of code

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SerialNumber, new { id = "sns" + i })
```

means that on the server you are trying to generate a `textarea` and set the `id` attribute to a value that includes a javascript variable which does not yet exist.

Its unclear even what the point of this would be. `id` attributes serve as selectors in javascript. Whats important is the `name` and `value` attributes when it comes to posting your data, and even if it could work, your generating duplicate `name` attributes which could not bind to you models collection property on post back.

For dynamically generating the html for collections, your `name` attributes need an indexer, for example `<input type="text" name="[0].SerialNumber" />`. Options for dynamically creating the html include using the [BeginCollectionitem()](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) helper, or a pure client side approach is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)

If all you are doing is post back an array of strings (the serial numbers) then you could use

```
var div = $("#divSerialNumbers"); // cache it
$('#Quantity').change(function() { // assumes you remove the pointless 'new { @id = "txtQty" }'
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val()); // use $(this) - don't traverse the DOM all over again
  if (!isNan(quantity) && quantity > 0) { // must check for NAN
    // note it does not seem necessary to use a table, as opposed to simply adding 4 inputs to the div, but
    div.empty(); // clear existing contents
    var table = $('</table>');
    for (i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
      var input = $('<input>').attr('name', 'SerialNumber');
      var cell = $('</td>').append(input);
      var row = $('</tr>').append(cell);
      table.append(row);
    }
    div.append(table).show(); // add the table and display it
  }
})
```

and your controller would need a parameter `string[] SerialNumber`, for example

```
public ActionResult Edit(string[] SerialNumber)
```