# How to fill a object in model via ajax, javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

Question rebuild.

I have a html table:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Lista pytan:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <table id="questionTable" border="0">
        <tbody id="questionTableBody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Which is builded dynamically via javascript AddRow() function called onclick:

```
function addRow(table, value)
    {
        var tab = document.getElementById(table);
        var rowCount = tab.rows.length;
        var row = tab.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var lp = document.createElement("label");
        lp.name = "lblLp[]";
        lp.className = "col-md-2 control-label";
        lp.textContent = "" + (rowCount + 1);
        cell1.appendChild(lp);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("label");
        element1.name = "lbl[]";
        element1.className = "col-md-2 control-label";
        element1.textContent = document.getElementById(value).value;
        cell2.appendChild(element1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "button";
        element2.name = "btn[]";
        element2.value = "Usun";
        element2.className = "btn btn-default";
        element2.addEventListener('click', function () {                
            deleteRow(table, row.rowIndex);
        });
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }
```

Based on this table i want to create a model right before calling

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add(AddQuestionnaireModel model)
```

in my controller.

My model looks like this:

```
public class AddQuestionnaireModel
{
    public QuestionnaireServiceReference.Questionnaire Questionnaire {get;set;}

    public AddQuestionnaireModel()
    {
        Questionnaire = new QuestionnaireServiceReference.Questionnaire();
    }
}
```

And Questionnaire is an object generated form EntityFramework:

```
public partial class Questionnaire
{
    public Questionnaire()
    {
        this.Question = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    public long questionnaire_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Question { get; set; }
}
```

Most important thing is that Questionnaire contain list of objects. How to via Ajax or Javascript fill a Model in my View?

I have add onclick funkction to my button submit button, named: fillQuestionnaire().

Can you help me build my fillQuestionnaire() javascript funkction? (or ajax if u have other ideas)

Comment: Hard to make any sense of your code and you need to post you models. If your trying to add dynamic content, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) may help

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for response. I updated question to be more precise.

Comment: Look at the link I gave you to understand how to dynamically add the html necessary to post back to a collection (you can also look at using the `BeginCollectionItemHelper`) The key is to correctly name you controls with indexers.

Comment: @StephenMuecke still dont understand how it works. however i rebuild my question and my idea. Maybe u will be able to answer for this one?

Comment: What is it that you think your script is doing? It seems to be creating some `<label>` elements (with a `name` attribute which is invalid for a label anyay) and a `<button>` element. Your not generating any controls at all (for editing or post back). Are you trying to add a table row containing controls for adding a new `Question` object that will be bound to the property `ICollection<Question> Question`?

Comment: exacly. each row contains a label with string (text of Question), button to remove a row, and other cells are labels with possible answers for that question.

Comment: `<label>` elements aren't controls - they don't post back anything. If you want to post back data you need inputs, textareas or selects. Still hard to understand what you trying to do. Is this for creating new questions and associated answers, or to display existing questions and possible answers, and allow a user to select an answer for a question?

Comment: This is a View to Create new Questionnaire: with questions and possible answers for them. So my intend was to create a model of Questionnaire in this View, and then send it to Controller. View is displaying only current 1 questionnare (current model). This is like administator page, user cant answer for question here. Just creating new Questionnaire. Ok so let say i will change label for Input text form. What next? still, how to create list and put it inside Questionnaire object

Comment: Then you need to study the link I gave you in my first comment. You need to generate inputs that are correctly named. You have not shown your model for `Question` but assuming it contains a property `string Title`, then your inputs would be `<input type="text" name="Question[0].Title ../>`, `<input type="text" name="Question[1].Title ../>` etc in order to bind to property `ICollection<Question> Question` when you submit the form.

Comment: I will try it then and give you a feedback. thank you anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke Works as hell! Thank you again! Add your comment as answer. I will accept it

Comment: @StephenMuecke One more question. What if i will remove one row? for example i have got row 1 2 and 3. I remove row 2. So i have got 1 and 3 row left. However controls in these rows are named like Question[1].Title and Question[3].Title what leads me to retrive only First row in my model (3 is gone becouse  there is no 2nd one, so how it could be 3rd:) ) . How to handle it?

Comment: By default collection indexers must start at zero and be consecutive. But you can overcome this by adding a hidden input for an `Index` with a value equal to the indexer. Again study the link I gave you (in your case it might look like `<input type="hidden" name="Question.Index" value="#" />` where `#` equals the indexer)