# How do I resolve ModelState.IsValid = false while binding a List type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post, modelstate

I'm getting an ModelState.IsValid = false from a List that contains a class object that has its own id's.

I've seen some examples of how to exclude class properties from the `[HttpPost]` method while binding that look like this:

```
[Bind(Exclude="Id,SomeOtherProperty")]
```

### My Question:

How do you exclude the Id that belongs to a *property* as it does with List? Or, if there's a better way of handling this, please shed some light on the subject.

Here's my **PostController.cs**:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 [ValidateInput(false)]
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,URL,IntroText,Body,Created,Modified,Author,Tags")] Post post)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid) /*ModelState.IsValid except for its not... */
     { 
           // this is failing so I unwrapped the code below temporarily
     }


         using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
         {
             var newPost = new Post
             {
                 Title = post.Title,
                 URL = post.URL,
                 IntroText = post.IntroText,
                 Body = replace,
                 Author = post.Author,
                 Tags = post.Tags

             };

             uwork.PostRepository.Insert(newPost);
             uwork.Commit();
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
         }


     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
 }
```

**Update:** Relevant excerpt from my [Create.cshtml](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/f0e63d6bb66c6c660929) (This turned out to be the problem.)

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offet-3" })
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tags[i].Id)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tags[i].Name)

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Gists:** [Post.cs](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/bb4d90e9f47b1c1d9b6b) | [Tag.cs](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/d812013030de19c6cdbe)

I wanted to include this picture so you could see, visually, what was failing. Each `Tag[i].Id` tag is causing the invalid state.

[image]

To restate my question, how do I omit the `List<Tag>` **Id** from my POST method and achieve valid state?

Comment: As always, use view models that represent only what you want to edit (but what makes you think that `ModelState` is invalid because of the value of `Id`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get what you mean about the view model, I'll make some modifications. thanks!

Comment: If your form does not include controls for the `Id` properties, then nothing will post back and the value of `Id` will be the default (i.e. 0 assuming its `int`) which is not invalid so I'm not sure what you have in the view that posting back a `null` value. You will need to show your view to be sure. But in any case if you don't want certain properties to be included, you should be using view models containing only those properties that should be edited/posted and then map the view model(s) to the data model(s).

Comment: Update: I added the relevant code, originally in a Gist, to highlight the question. @StephenMuecke had it right, I left a hidden field in my view.

Comment: Have just seen you edit. The real problem is the `@for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` What you should be doing if you want to create 4 tags is to initialize you collection of Tags with 4 default `Tag` items in the controller before you pass the model to the view and then use `@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++)` so you get correct 2-way model binding (although you can still delete the input for the `Id` property because its not required)

Comment: @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++) <--- tried this, it crashed the application each time. I get ERROR: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Having said that, are you really always requiring the user to include 4 tags? Your should consider dynamically adding tags in the view as required

Comment: I'm essentially writing a blog as a learning exercise. I figured I would get  the functionality working and then later re-factor as I learn more.

Comment: For future reference, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) shows how you can dynamically add new items to the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@StephenMuecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) pointed out in the comments of the OP. I just needed to remove the field from the View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tags[i].Id)
```

Now the ModelState.IsValid returns true.