# save variable from <select> in View into the ViewModel ASP-NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

So I have a ViewModel with this attribute

```
public string number { get; set; }
```

And in my View I have the next drop down list:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

How do I save the value that gets selected on the drop down list into the `number` attribute from my ViewModel?
Usually I would use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.number, listObject)` but the dropdownlist that I'm trying to create has to be dynamically created with JQuery, therefore I can't use the HtmlHelper.

**EDIT:** As answered in the comments, what I want to accomplish may be possible with the html helper but I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Of course you can use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.number, ...)` - just pass an empty list initially and add the options using javascript. But the key is to give your control a name matching the property name - `<select name="number">`

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a button that when you click it, it creates a new drop down list. That's why I think that it has to be "Dynamically created with JQuery"(or javascript, not too sure of, because I don't know how many times the user is gonna make a new drop down list. So I don't see how to do it with the HtmlHelper.

Comment: You need to give a bit more information about waht you are really tring to do. You can only create one dropdown associated with property `number` - any others with the same name would just be ignored when you post (unless your property was `public string[] number { get; set; }`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Also, I assume that if I want the selected value to be saved in a `public List<string> someList { get; set; }` attribute I'd just have to set the name to `name="number[index]"`. **Edit** : Okay I just tried this and it worked.

Comment: To expand on previous comment: you can use `@Html.DropDownListFor`, but make it hidden initially - then *show* it with javascript.  This would ensure correct binding to a single property (as in the question code (single `number` value).  Maybe update the question to show that there may be multiple 'number' to be returned?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hm right, at first I thought that what you are suggesting would not work because the maximum amount of dropdowns to be created/displayed depends on a variable from a database, therefore not knowing the maximum amount of dropdowns to be created at the time that the HTML view loaded. But now that I think about it, the max amount of possible dropdowns could be passed as a parameter to the view, and then use a `@{for ...}` to create multiple `@Html.DropDownListFor` depending on that number. But I don't think I'm going to do it that way. (Not sure about how that'd work anyway)

Comment: @JosePablo, My initial comment relating to using the helper was related to your question (which does not have any mention of multiple dropdowns). In any case you should always start by using a helper so that you can inspect the html they generate and use that for you own client side templates. You might also be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes thank you! My bad for explaining myself poorly in the question.