# MVC, Posting Models containing a list of another model and additional Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a the following classes

```
public class Course
  {
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Occasion> Occasions { get; set; } 
  }
 public class Occasion
  { 
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course Course{ get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; } 
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
  }
```

and view Models

```
public class CourseModel
  {
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<OccasionModel> Occasions { get; set; } 
  }
public class OccasionModel
  { 
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
  }
```

My intention is to have a view where I can create/edit a new course with one or several occasions.  I want have just one line where I write an occasion for a course, and a new line that shows up only if I choose to add a new occasion.  Understandably, the size of the list is determied by the user.

I have tried using partial pages as well as using helper Html.EditorFor along with a template view page for occasionModel in Shared folder in the similar fashion as one would generate a checkboxes for a list in a model.  I did google a lot but the questions are either unanswered or in other languages.  It is probably possible to make a page where one creates the course without occasions and then using a partial page edits the course so that it adds new occasions.  Isn't there an easy way of creating both the course and its occasions in one go?  Thanks

Comment: You can using forms in HTML, but this is a broad topic that will take long to explain

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) shows one possible method.