# repeating create form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net mvc and would like some pointers on where to start with this.

I can generate a create form to create a single record but what I'd like is the ability to fill in some details for a record say:

Type
Description
Cost

but once that first set of details is filled in a second set of boxes appear to allow a second set of data to be filled in then a third set and so on then press save to save all the records.

I'm using entity framework code first and MVC 5.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Search for some asp.net tutorials and maybe get a book and read up on the mvc framework. There's not much anybody can do for you here if you expect to get help without providing some code related to your question

Comment: Suggest you start by looking at the [BeginCollectionItem](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) helper (you will need ajax to call a method that returns a partial view. For a pure client side option, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) shows one option.

Comment: You can also use  knockoutjs as client side option.https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/dynamic-repeating-field-groups-in-asp-net-mvc-with-just-a-dash-of-knockout-js/