# Get list data on view in controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view in which I have rendered partial view in a loop. There is a list and partial view have is binded with each item in a list. I am not getting the value of the list on controller after value is entered.

Here is my view:

```
<table id="resourceRequirement" class="table" width="100%" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#dfdfdf;">
            <td><div align="center">PRIORITY</div></td>
            <td><div align="center">SYSTEM RESOURCE / COMPONENT</div></td>
            <td><div align="center">RECOVERY TIME OBJECTIVE</div></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ResourceRequirement)
        {
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_ResourceRequirement.cshtml", item)
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my partial view:

```
@model DisasterManagementSystem.Models.BusinessImpactAnalysis.ResourceRequirement
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.priority)<br />
        <div style="color:red;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.priority)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.systemresource)<br />
        <div style="color:red;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.systemresource)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.receveryTime)<br />
        <div style="color:red;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.receveryTime)
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my list:

```
public List<ResourceRequirement> ResourceRequirement { get; set; }
```

And the class is here:

```
public class ResourceRequirement
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string priority { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string systemresource { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string receveryTime { get; set; }
}
```

Please advise when i am trying to get the list from model on post I am getting the list as null.

Comment: Maybe the controller action that rendered this view didn't supply any value in the model?

Comment: initially blank form is rendered after filling the details it is not returning values. returning only null

Comment: Can you show the controller code too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use of a `foreach` loop and a partial is generating duplicate `name` attributes without indexers (so cannot bind to a collection) and duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html).

Instead of a partial view, use an `EditorTemplate`. Rename your current partial view to `ResourceRequirement.cshtml` (i.e. to match the name of the class) and place it in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (or in the `/Views/yourController/EditorTemplates` folder)

Then in the main view, remove the `foreach` loop and replace it with

```
<tbody>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ResourceRequirement)
</tbody>
```

The `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and generates the correct html for each item in your collection. If you inspect the html you will now see the correct name attributes in your form controls

```
<input type="text" name="ResourceRequirement[0].priority" .... />
<input type="text" name="ResourceRequirement[1].priority" .... />
<input type="text" name="ResourceRequirement[2].priority" .... />
```

etc. which will bind to your model when you submit the form (compare this with what your currently generating)

Comment: What should be my folder path for the editor template. I didnt got your meaning of line "/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder (on in the /Views/yourController/EditorTemplates folder)"

Comment: Can you guide how to add a row in the above table using jquery?? So that we get the data

Comment: Lets assume your controller is named `HomeController`, then It can be in either the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` folder or the `Views/Home/EditorTempates/` folder. The view engine searches for `EditorTemplates` first in the controller specific folder, and if it does not find one, then it searches in the `Shared` folder. This allows you to have multiple `EditorTemplates` for each class. In you case, just rename it and move it to the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder

Comment: As for adding a new row using jquery, that's an entirely different question. Start by studying at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)

Answer (score 2):

As You want List to be passed in the View just in Controller pass the List through a method like

```
public Actionresult List()
{
  var search = from m in db.resourcerequirement select m;
  return PartialView("_List",search.tolist());
}
```

After that in Partial View _List

```
@model DisasterManagementSystem.Models.BusinessImpactAnalysis.ResourceRequirement
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.priority)<br />
        <div style="color:red;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.priority)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.systemresource)<br />
        <div style="color:red;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.systemresource)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.receveryTime)<br />
        <div style="color:red;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.receveryTime)
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

To show Partial View

```
@{Html.RenderAction("List", "ControllerName");}
```