# How can I automatically generate new Guid inside of list<Expense> from viewmodel and pass value to foreach loop of Controller using an Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc. How can I automatically generate new Guid inside of  foreach loop? I am using `List<Expense>` in view model and  GUID as PrimaryKey, how I insert a multiple row from datatable to database insertion?

Here is my view model. I can insert a single row data, but if I insert more than one row data, it will show the error like :

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Expense__EBE72675160F4887'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Expense'.\r\nThe statement
>   has been terminated.

```
 public System.Guid MaintenanceId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ExpenseSummaryId { get; set; }
    public string BillNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BillDate { get; set; }
    public string VechicleNo { get; set; }
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> UserRightsId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string ProviderCity { get; set; }
    public string ProviderState { get; set; }
    public string ProviderCountry { get; set; }
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
    public int Sno { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EditedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastActiveOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> RowID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CreatedSessionID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> EditedSessionID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> OfflineMode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> OfflineID { get; set; }

    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRight UserRight { get; set; }
```

Here is My Controller

```
  public JsonResult SaveOrder(TruckVM TVM)
    {
        bool status = false;
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         using (TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities())
            {
              var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
              maintenance ObjMaintenance = new maintenance 
                { 
                 MaintenanceId=guid,
                 BillNo=TVM.BillNo,
                 BillDate=TVM.BillDate,
                 Amount=TVM.Amount
                 };                   

                foreach (var i in TVM.Expenses)
                {
                    ObjMaintenance.Expenses.Add(i);

                }

                db.maintenances.Add(ObjMaintenance);
                //db.serviceproviders.Add(ObjServiceProvider);
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new  { status = status } };
    }`
```

here is my view

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var orderItems = [];
        $('#add').click(function () {
            var isValidItem = true;
            
       
            if ($('#Particulars').val().trim() == '') {
                isValidItem = false;
                $('#Particulars').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#Particulars').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }

            if (!($('#qty').val().trim() != '' && !isNaN($('#qty').val().trim()))) {
                isValidItem = false;
                $('#qty').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#qty').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }

            if (!($('#unitprice').val().trim() != '' && !isNaN($('#unitprice').val().trim()))) {
                isValidItem = false;
                $('#unitprice').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#unitprice').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
            //Add item to list if valid
            if (isValidItem) {
                orderItems.push({
                  
                    Particulars: $('#Particulars').val().trim(),
                    qty: parseInt($('#qty').val().trim()),
                    unitprice: parseFloat($('#unitprice').val().trim()),
                    TotalAmount: parseInt($('#qty').val().trim()) * parseFloat($('#unitprice').val().trim())

                });

                //Clear fields
                $('#Particulars').val('').focus();
                $('#qty').val('')
                $('#unitprice').val('')
                

            }

            GeneratedItemsTable();
        });

        $('#submit').click(function () {
            //validation of order
            var isAllValid = true;
            if (orderItems.length == 0) {
                $('#orderItems').html('<span style="color:red;">Please add order items</span>');
                isAllValid = false;
            }

            if ($('#BillNo').val().trim() == '') {
                $('#BillNo').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
                isAllValid = false;
            }
            else {
                $('#BillNo').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }

            if ($('#BillDate').val().trim() == '') {
                $('#BillDate').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
                isAllValid = false;
            }
            else {
                $('#BillDate').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }

            //Save if valid
            if (isAllValid) {
                var data = {
                    BillNo: $('#BillNo').val().trim(),
                    BillDate: $('#BillDate').val().trim(),
                    Amount: $('#Amount').val().trim(),
                    Expenses: orderItems
                }

                $(this).val('Please wait...');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/VechicleMaintenance/SaveOrder',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (d) {
                        //check is successfully save to database 
                        if (d.status == true) {
                            //will send status from server side
                            alert('Successfully done.');
                            //clear form
                            orderItems = [];
                            $('#BillNo').val('');
                            $('#BillDate').val('');
                            $('#orderItems').empty();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                        $('#submit').val('Save');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error. Please try again.');
                        $('#submit').val('Save');
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        function GeneratedItemsTable() {
            if (orderItems.length > 0) {
                var $table = $('<table/>');
                $table.append('<thead><tr><th>Particulars</th><th>qty</th><th>unitprice</th><th>TotalAmount</th></tr></thead>');
                var $tbody = $('<tbody/>');
                $.each(orderItems, function (i, val) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                   
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.Particulars));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.qty));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.unitprice));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.TotalAmount));
                    $tbody.append($row);
                });
                $table.append($tbody);
                $('#orderItems').html($table);
            }
        }

     


    });
```

```html
 <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                   
                    <td>Particulars</td>
                    <td>qty</td>
                    <td>unitprice</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Particulars" />
                        <span class="error">Item name required</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="qty" />
                        <span class="error">Valid quantity required</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="unitprice" />
                        <span class="error">Valid rate required</span>
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="button" id="add" value="add"    />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="orderItems" class="tablecontainer">

            </div>
            <div style="padding:10px 0px; text-align:right">
                <input id="submit" type="button" value="Save" style="padding:10px 20px" />
            </div>
```

Comment: Your table key is auto-generated or you should assign the key value yourself? If it is auto-generated, you should not assign any value to it, else you can set the key value using `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: You need to create a new `Guid` in the `foreach (var i in TVM.Expenses)` and assign it to each`Expenses` object (just as your doing for the `ObjMaintenance` object)

Comment: #Reza Aghaei  :  
My Table is Not Auto Generated,I am assigned Guid.NewGuid ,But it will work for single row ,If i inserting More than one row it will showing Error.So that only i am posting entire code , i don't know Where i could make mistake.

Comment: #Stephen Muecke: Can u explain elaborately. I Can't understand, i am almost done what u said.but it still happend Error

Comment: Your adding `Expenses` objects to your database. You have not shown the model for `Expenses` but I assume it has an ID property which is a `Guid`, so therefore inside the inner loop, you need `i.ExpenseId = Guid.NewGuid();` (and its `@` not `#` to notify a user)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thank u so much , I cleared My Error ,Data Saved Successfully, It almost took 3weeks ,with in 3 mints u cleared this thank u so much

Comment: yes , u right ,i am asked so many developers, no one can shortout this issue, but u did, once again thank u so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating a new `Guid` for the `MaintenanceId` property of `ObjMaintenance`, but you're not creating the `Guid` for the ID property of each `Expenses` objuect that you're adding. Assuming that property is named `ExpenseId`, then you loop needs to be

```
....
maintenance ObjMaintenance = new maintenance 
{ 
    MaintenanceId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ....
};                   
foreach (var i in TVM.Expenses)
{
    i.ExpenseId = Guid.NewGuid(); // add this
    ObjMaintenance.Expenses.Add(i);
}
db.maintenances.Add(ObjMaintenance);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Side note: I suggest you look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) for dynamically adding new items to a collection which allows you to add, edit and delete on the fly in 1/10 of the code you currently have.