# MVC POST Model with List to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider these two view models

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public int PersonAge {get; set;}

    public virtual PersonJobSplitViewModel JobSplit { get; set; } // hold each split
    public virtual List<PersonJobSplitViewModel> JobSplits { get; set; } //contain all splits
}

public class PersonJobSplitViewModel
{
    public int PersonJobSplitId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string JobRole { get; set; }
    public decimal SplitPercentage { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonViewModel PersonViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Each person can have between 1 - 3 jobs.

I have a Create view which is bound to my `PersonViewModel` and in my controller's GET method I am creating an instance of `List<PersonJobSplitViewModel>` with a capacity of 3 and assigning it to `PersonViewModel.JobSplits`

```
@model MySolution.Web.ViewModels.PersonViewModel

...

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.JobSplits.Capacity; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobSplit.JobRole);
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobSplit.SplitPercentage);
}
```

This results in the role and percentage inputs being rendered to the view 3 times. My POST method is expecting a `PersonViewModel` however `PersonViewModel.JobSplits` is coming in as `null`. The `JobSplit` property contains one of my 3 splits, as I kind of expect.

**So how do I post the model bound with it's full list of JobSplits through to the controller?**

I've found similar things have been answered previously but I cant seem to find a straight forward solution that is relevant to **MVC5** and relates to tagging a list to a large model as apposed to just passing a list to the controller.

**Update**

I've now tried doing the following

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.JobSplits.Capacity; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobSplits[i].JobRole);
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobSplits[i].SplitPercentage);
}
```

But I get:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: What if you change `.Capacity` to `.Count`?

Comment: This is correct, will post the answer for anyone else's benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out straight after posting.

**Controller**

```
//Prep view Model
PersonViewModel viewModel = new PersonViewModel();
List<PersonJobSplitViewModel> instantiatedSplitCount = new List<PersonJobSplitViewModel>(3);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    instantiatedSplitCount.Add(null);
}

viewModel.JobSplits = instantiatedSplitCount;
return View(viewModel);
```

**View**

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.JobSplits.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobSplits[i].JobRole);
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobSplits[i].SplitPercentage);
}
```

It seems doing a check on capacity was the problem, assigning 3 nulls to the list before I pass through, and then checking the count was the solution.

Not pretty in my Controller but if anyone else can suggest a more syntactic solution please share.

Comment: You have indicated _Each person can have between 1 - 3 jobs._ so if any of your properties have validation attributes, this will fail. You really should consider dynamically adding the `JobSplits` (a few examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)

Comment: Also unclear why you have both `PersonJobSplitViewModel JobSplit` and `List<PersonJobSplitViewModel> JobSplits` in your model.