# MVC make list property required on first loop only

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say I have the following list properties being rendered to my create view:

```
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SiteSplits.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteSplits[i].CostCode, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-3"})
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteSplits[i].CostCode, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteSplits[i].SplitPercentage, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-3"})
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteSplits[i].SplitPercentage, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

This results in x3 cost code and split percentages which are passed back to the controller in a list on POST.

I've put a required annotation on the `CostCode` and `SplitPercentage` in the view model, which is resulting in all 3 of the Split/Codes being required.

Is there any way of making just the `CostCode` and `SplitPercentage` Required on just the first loop and have it ignore the validation for the second two so they are merely optional?

Comment: I already gave you the solution to solve this is the comments to your self answer in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067583/mvc-post-model-with-list-to-controller) - you cannot make the attributes apply to only one instance (and in any case, what of the user entered 2 or 3)

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen this, will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you could include an addition property in your  model say

```
public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
```

and then use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar validation attribute on the other properties

```
[RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired")]
public string CostCode { get; set; }
```

and in the GET method, populate the `SiteSplits` collection with 3 default objects, setting the first one with `IsRequired = true;` and include a hidden input for the `IsRequired` property.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SiteSplits[i].IsRequired)
```

However, this makes no sense in relation to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067583/mvc-post-model-with-list-to-controller) where you have indicated you want between 1 and 3 items. If the user added all 3, then the last 2 would not be validated and you could be saving invalid data.

A better option is to allow the user to dynamically add new items as required, which can be done by using the `BeginCollectionItem` helper or by creating a html template and copying and appending it to your collection (and updating its collection indexers) as discussed in the following answers

1. [POST a form array without successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796)
2. [Submit same Partial View called multiple times data to
   controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)
3. [Set class validation for dynamic textbox in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)

An example of using the `BeginCollectionItem` is also included in [this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UjxtUW) for a working example using a html template based on the models posted in your last question

Comment: Thanks to the effort you went to with this, much appreciated.