# Taking in multiple dates from the UI and binding to the ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

Lets say my ViewModel has a property in it that is a list of Dates

```
IList<DateTime> concertDates;
```

My plan in my cshtml file is to allow the user to select multiple concert dates and when they hit a submit button, retrieve this information in the controller.

I am assuming in order to allow the user to select multiple dates I would add a DatePicker widget to the page and allow the user to select a date from it. When the user selects a date from it, the date will get added to a list in JavaScript. Then somehow this list needs to be converted to JSON and set to the ViewModel..

How would it be possible to bind the IList concertDates ViewModel property?

Comment: This is kinda hard to answer. So many ways you can go here. What have you tried? Sounds like you have the idea. Add some date pickers, bind some events to the datepicker changed, append to an array....ajax the array to the controller.

Comment: I know I can AJAX the array to the controller but lets say I have a large form on the page with Textboxes, DropDownLists, etc.. and I submit to my Save action method which accepts a ViewModel. All of the basic fields automatically get bound to the view model. How would I do the same for a completely custom scenario like this multi-date picker idea?

Comment: Use Ajax Call, get all date's in Javascript and form array or Json format, and hit the Controller,

Comment: Your simply need to dynamically generate new inputs with `<input name="concertDates" ... />` using javascript (and attach a datepicker to the new element). Ajax is not required unless you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Lets say the input field ends up with values like: 1/1/2016, 1/2/2016, 1/3/2016 as the text. When the user hits submit I highly doubt MVC will automatically know that those 3 dates get bound to the IList<DateTime> ConcertDates property in my page's ViewModel. That is where my confusion comes in. Do I manually set Model.ConcertDates to the Textbox.Text in JS?

Comment: Did you even bother to try it. If you had, you would have realized it did work!

Comment: @StephenMuecke It does not work... As a simple test I added the following to my form: <input asp-for="ConcertDates" type="hidden" name="ConcertDates" id="ConcertDates" value="1/12/2015, 2/12/2016" />

Comment: NO! You create 3 inputs (using jquery), each with `<input type="text"  name="ConcertDates" />` and enter a valid date in each

Comment: ohh!! you really need a separate input for each one? I had no idea that is how mvc worked with auto binding. I will give it a shot. Lets say in my case the user selects several dates from a calendar and I have them all stored in an array. How do I go from the dates in that array to dynamically generating multiple inputs for each date?

Comment: Note that this only works when your collection is a value type. For complex objects you need indexers in the name - refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) for more complex scenarios

Comment: It works! At first I was sending it using the default JavaScript dateformat but when I did .toLocaleDateString() it is sending it in as a short date and working. Thank you so much and I apologize for not figuring this out sooner. So is this basically the only way to do something like this unless I am using a 3rd party widget that knows how to bind to a List for you?