# how to bind dynamic items to list in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a a ViewModel that its contains List of another ViewModel Like :

```
 public class EditProductViewModel
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
public List<ProductPriceItemViewModel> ProductList { get; set; }
}

  public class ProductPriceItemViewModel
{
    public int PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public int SalePrice { get; set; }
}
```

in View User Can Add New row and Add New `Product`  for do this I use a jquery like this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#addnewproductprice', function () {
    $("#ProductPriceList tr:last").before("<tr>"+ $("#ProductPriceList tr#template").html()+"</tr>");
});

     <tr id="template" class="hidden">
                            <td><input type="text" class="txtpurchase form-control" name="ProductList[index].PurchasePrice" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="txtsale form-control" name="ProductList[index].SalePrice" /></td>
<span class="btnSavePrice btn btn-xs btn-info">Save</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

but when click submit and getting in Debig mode in Controller ,`ProductList` is `null` . model binder dont bind data , I dont know ?
is there a way to do this?

Comment: the name of the input tags `name="ProductList[index].PurchasePrice"` will not bind to the Class ProductList, The name should match the Class property name.

Comment: Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: @StephenMuecke wow ! Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: @UthmanRahimi, Another one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) which was focused on ensuring the dynamically generated items has client side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a question related this topic , Can I have ask here ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I have some hidden fields like this `PurchaseDetails[1457338572841].StoreDetails[1437338542886].ProductId` , it doesnt work and cant bind , but when change it to `PurchaseDetails[1457338572841].StoreDetails[0].ProductId` its work . when set ordinal numbers its work fine . why ?

Comment: There is nothing at all in your models relating to properties `StoreDetails` which contains a property `ProductId` so its hard to understand. But if `.StoreDetails[1437338542886].ProductId` is not binding, it suggest you do not have a hidden input for the indexer - e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="PurchaseDetails[1457338572841].StoreDetails.Index" value="1437338542886" />`

Comment: how can I show to you my model ?

Comment: Since this question is closed, I suggest you ask a new question showing the relevant models, how you are generating the html and the signature of the controller method you posting back to. But the key issue when binding collections is that the indexers must start at zero and be consecutive, **or** you must include a hidden input for the `Index` value which matches the indexer in the `name` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks , problem was `Index`