# How to add validation on a dynamic textbox based from the model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have this Jquery code:

```
$('.additems').click(function () {
            $table = $('.item');

   $table.append('<tr> <td> <input type="textbox" name="test"> </td>   </tr>');

});
```

And I want to enable the validation from the `[Required]` attribute of my model who contains the property `test`

I tried adding the autogenerated html from the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` which is 
`<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="test" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>` but it's not working.

How do I do it?

Comment: In your view, temporarily create the elements using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.test)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.test)` and inspect the html it generates. And its `type="text"`, not `"textbox"`. And best guess is your trying to dynamically add new items to a collection, in which case refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)

Comment: So get the generated html and append it with the same format/contents?

Comment: Yes, If the property your bind to is `IEnumerable<string> test` then it will work, but if your binding to a collection of complex obects, then you will need indexers as per the answers I linked to.

Comment: Oh I didnt put indexers for the sake of simplicity but that is what I am doing right now. Anyway I'll try what you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different solution

```
    $('.additems').click(function () {
    $table = $('.item'); 
    $table.append('<tr> <td> <input type="textbox" class="myReq" name="test"> </td>   </tr>');

});
function foo() {
    $(".myReq").each(function () {
        //Your Control
    });
}
```