# Error inserting multiple rows in database MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following [this tutorial](http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/mvc/insert-multiple-record-to-database-at-a-time-aspnet-mvc4) in order to insert multiple rows in my database. Following the exact code from the tutorial i was able to do it, but now i have a problem. My view:

```
<style>
    th {
        text-align: left;
    }   
    td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add more</a></div>
    <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Aluno</th>
            <th>Presente?</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                    @if (Model != null && i.EventId != null && i.EventId != 0)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[j].EventId)
                    }
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].UserCourseId, (SelectList)ViewBag.UserCourseId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a[j].check)</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (j > 0)
                        {
                            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        j++;
            }
        }
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
}
</div>
```

And the script in the view:

```
<script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                //1. Add new row
                $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
                    var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
                    var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

                    var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                    $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
                    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                        // Replaced Name
                        var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                        var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                        $(this).attr('name', newN);
                        //Replaced value
                        var type = $(this).attr('type');
                        if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                            $(this).attr('value', '');
                        }
                        $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

                    });
                    $trLast.after($trNew);

                    // Re-assign Validation
                    var form = $("form")
                        .removeData("validator")
                        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                });

                // 2. Remove
                $('a.remove').live("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });

            });
        </script>
```

In the tutorial, in the foreach:

```
foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <tr style="border:1px solid black">                   
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].UserCourseId, (SelectList)ViewBag.UserCourseId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a[j].check)</td>
                    <td>
```

It uses @Html.TextBox instead of dropdownlist and editorfor, and in that way works, but in this way when i click to "Add more" it doesn't do anything, but i need to be able to use a dropdownlist and editorfor. I think i need to change something in the jquery but i don't know what since i'm new in that area. What do i need to change in order to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you wanting to dynamically add and remove collection items, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options. (the code you have shown can never work for deleting items)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your answer. Actually i will not use the remove. I just need to know why the dropdownlistfor and editorfor doesn't work in this code, and how to resolve it. If there is not a way to make it work, then i will check for other options.

Comment: The code in that tutorial is dreadful.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you recommend a better one? A tutorial step by step, i'm a novice

Comment: See the link in my first comment, of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689). And do not use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (you will never get true 2-way model binding)